# Ubuntu 16.04 x64 unable to power on bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

My bluetooth device fails (powers off) randomly and I can't turn it back on again unless I reboot (somethimes power off/on my laptop).
I have Lenovo Y50-70 laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Trying to power off/on bluetooth from unity indicator panel icon or from `System Settings -> Bluetooth` logs the following:

```
bluetoothd[18093]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
```

Device is not blocked:

```
$ sudo rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

hciconfig lists the device as down:

```
$ sudo hciconfig -a hci0
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: E8:B1:FC:DC:DC:95  ACL MTU: 1021:5  SCO MTU: 96:5
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:281058 acl:11356 sco:0 events:297 errors:0
    TX bytes:28099 acl:52 sco:0 commands:210 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

And can't be brought up or reset:

```
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
```

Retarting the servies gives the following log errors, even though it seems running

```
~$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Du 2017-09-03 13:05:40 EEST; 3s ago
    Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 18093 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1
Memory: 1016.0K
    CPU: 5ms
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
        └─18093 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

sep 03 13:05:40 burfee bluetoothd[18093]: Error adding Link Loss service
sep 03 13:05:40 burfee bluetoothd[18093]: Not enough free handles to register service
sep 03 13:05:40 burfee bluetoothd[18093]: Not enough free handles to register service
sep 03 13:05:40 burfee bluetoothd[18093]: Not enough free handles to register service
sep 03 13:05:40 burfee bluetoothd[18093]: Current Time Service could not be registered
sep 03 13:05:40 burfee bluetoothd[18093]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
sep 03 13:05:40 burfee bluetoothd[18093]: Not enough free handles to register service
sep 03 13:05:40 burfee bluetoothd[18093]: Not enough free handles to register service
sep 03 13:05:40 burfee bluetoothd[18093]: Sap driver initialization failed.
sep 03 13:05:40 burfee bluetoothd[18093]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
```

Trying to power it on from bluetoothctl:

```
$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller E8:B1:FC:DC:DC:95 burfee-0 [default]
[NEW] Device A4:77:33:77:AB:B3 A4-77-33-77-AB-B3
[NEW] Device 88:C6:26:72:12:7E Logitech BT Adapter
[NEW] Device 84:38:35:3B:BB:94 Apple Wireless Trackpad
[bluetooth]# power on
Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

I even tried a kernel upgrade from 4.4 to 4.6

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.6.0-040600-generic #201606100558 SMP Fri Jun 10 10:01:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit: upgraded now:

```
$ uname -a
Linux burfee 4.10.0-33-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 14:07:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Device:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c270]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 145f:01ae Trust 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It seems to crash mostly when the laptop is doing more processing, but also had it crash when I was just moving the cursor on the screen or opening Krusader. I notice when it crashes instantly, because I am using an Apple Magic Trackpad.

I don't have a Fn hotkey on my laptop to hard power bluetooth off/on, or I couldn't find it, so the only option is to power off/on the laptop, which is quite a pain, since this problem occurs often.

Comment: Why an unsupported kernel is installed? Update the kernel by `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04` and reboot.

Comment: I did mention that I updated to see if it fixes the problem. The same issue is present with 4.4 kernel as well.

Comment: That command should install the 4.10 kernel.

Comment: Same issues with this kernel as well: `Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)`

Comment: And what is the BT device? `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

Comment: added to question now

Comment: I have exactly the same device and I have no problems. Must be a hardware issue. You can try to update BIOS.

Comment: Is there any other way I could power it on/off without rebooting, besides what I mentioned I tried in the question?

Comment: upgraded to the latest BIOS on Lenovo website: problem is still there

Comment: Burdu, did you ever get this fixed? I have the exact same error I have to keep restarting my laptop for over and over >:(

Comment: No, the issue is still there..

Comment: As a work-around, when bluetooth crashes and I can't get it up, I suspend my system for a few seconds, then turn it back on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this, not as a solution, but as a work-around, as it may help others.
I am encountering bluetooth issues on 2 different laptops, both with Ubuntu 16.04 and the work-arounds are different:

- for the first laptop, the one in the question, If I instantly notice that bluetooth crashed, I go to the Unity bluetooth indicator panel icon, then switch the toggle to off, wait a few moments for it to turn off, then turn it back on. Sometimes, if it takes too long after the crash and I don't do the toggle switching, for some weird reason, it doesn't work anymore. Other times, it doesn't work even if I react immediately after the crash. When this happens, I suspend my laptop for a few moments, then wake it back.
- For the second laptop, the toggle trick does not work. What works is opening the bluetooth settings, either by searching for the Unity lens, or by going to System Settings > Bluetooth, and turn it off and back on from the toggle here. As a side note, this work-around always works for this laptop, but does not work for the first laptop.

Why the laptops react in different ways to those toggle switches, I don't know, but, after weeks of trying different ways to fix the bluetooth issue, these are the solution I found to not have to restart my laptops when I can no longer use my Magic Trackpad.